# UITableView - How to specify start position for horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

Could anybody please help me understand if there is a way to provide the start position for horizontal scrolling in UITableView?

Basically, I have enabled horizontal scrolling by giving content inset like [self.tblData setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,500)];. But, I do not want the section headers to scroll. Is there a way that I can fix the section headers while scrolling horizontally?

Comment: u need  the table scroll for both direction

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have implemented the scroll in both directions, its just that I want to start the horizontal scrolling from the position below the current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll the view horizontally, i suggest that you should replace UITableView with UICollectionView。

If you want to scroll just one cell horizontally, you can add UIScrollView into cell.contentView.

Comment: I think this is the best approach that you've suggested. Will implement this and let you know how it worked.